# Ordering lattice bwplot

Tags: r, lattice

I am plotting data by week using a lattice bwplot and am having trouble figuring out how it is deciding to sort the plots for each day. It showing (left to right, top to bottom): Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday, Monday, Thursday. Rather, I want it to show in the order of (left to right, top to bottom): Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday. Unfortunately I can't post an image to show the exact plot since I don't have a 10 reputation on SO.

Here are the first 6 rows of my data (the object is too big for dput). Imagine this repeating for 3,810 rows...

```
          X            datetime    useKW       genKW    netKW index     WkDay
22096 264719 2013-07-01 05:00:00 1.470133 0.003050000 1.467083 22096    Monday
22216 263279 2013-07-02 05:00:00 2.231567 0.002433333 2.229133 22216   Tuesday
22328 261839 2013-07-03 05:00:00 1.709833 0.003116667 1.706717 22328 Wednesday
22474 260399 2013-07-04 05:00:00 1.445117 0.003116667 1.442000 22474  Thursday
22607 258959 2013-07-05 05:00:00 1.428533 0.003116667 1.425417 22607    Friday
23002 254639 2013-07-08 05:00:00 1.528633 0.003233333 1.525400 23002    Monday
        HM   H_M
22096 0500 05:00
22216 0500 05:00
22328 0500 05:00
22474 0500 05:00
22607 0500 05:00
23002 0500 05:00
```

And, here is my function call for the bWplot:

```
bwplot(netKW~H_M|WkDay,data=DS1, scales=list(x=list(rot=45)), ylab='netKW', xlab=xlab, main=main)
```

I have looked into other posts about defining the lattice plot order and they seem to be leading to a common solution of changing the factor level order... In my case, it would be for WkDay. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to apply this to my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DS1$WkDay <- factor( DS1$WkDay, levels=c( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 
                                           'Thursday', 'Friday') )
```

You should realize that lattice plots are from bottom to top, so expecting it to be from top to bottom is swimming against the stream so to speak. See the `as.table` argument on the `?bwplot` help page for a mechanism to alter that default behavior.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for the example I posted. I had been circling around this solution for a while and didn't realize it would be that easy. Now I just have to figure out hot to make the levels dynamic since my program allows the user to define the days the want to inspect. Thanks again!